# Table cell positions adapting to table cell sizes. Is it possible?

Tags: css, css-tables

I am a relatively new web developer and i normally use flex-box for these kinds of situations.
I have to use table for this project because the liquid template i am customizing is using `display:table;`.

I want images to reposition themselves and close the whitespace between cells.
Is it even possible in a table layout?
I share a fragment of SCSS of the screenshot to give an idea.
Sorry for the style i still have some problems with the stack overflow editor when it comes to nested code. You can match the classes with border colors.

```
.collection-products{
    border:2px solid rgba(222,45,67);

    &:after{
    display: table;
    content: '';
    clear: both;

.collection-product{
    border:1px solid blue; 

    display: block;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding-left: $products_padding;
    margin-bottom: $products_padding;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba($color_product_bg, 0.2);

    .table{
    border:1px solid green;

    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px; // this behaves as min-height
    .cell{
      border:1px solid red;

      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      img{
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0 auto;
        @include default-transition(opacity);
      }

 }//close .cell
 }//close .table

 }//close .collection-product
 }//close .collection-products
```

A screen shot to demonstrate the wanted effect.

[image]
I read about tables but i couldn't find an answer to this problem.
Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with `display: table;`

Comment: Then i have to write the system again with flex box. What a drag.. :)